# java Vector usage

Tags: java, vector, struct

I'm  trying to read a .txt file, and i want to parse/tokenize each line so that i can load to a struct. finally, the struct will be added/pushed to a vector of type struct. But, the [addEllement()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/vector_addelement.htm) function is not working! Any one who knows how to add a struct to a [vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)?

Sample code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.*;

/*
 * STRUCT TO STORE PARSED DATA
 */
class my_struct
{
    String name;
    String id;
    String comment;
}
public class read 
{
  //Vector of type my_struct to store data
public static Vector<my_struct> plugin_group_list=new Vector<my_struct>();
   try 
        {
            //opening my file
            File file = new File("file.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            my_struct[] list_plugin_param=new my_struct[100];
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] result = line.split("~");
                 for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
                 {
                     list_plugin_param[x] = new my_plugin();
                     if(x==0)
                     {
                         list_plugin_param[x].name=result[x];
                     }              
                     if(x==1)
                     {
                         list_plugin_param[x].id=result[x];
                     }  
                     if(x==2)
                     {
                         list_plugin_param[x].comment=result[x];
                     }
                 }
plugin_group_list.addEllement(list_plugin_param);//this doesn't work for me
            }
            fileReader.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**file.txt** looks like below

```
John~0001~this is John
smith~0002~this is smith
..
..
..
```

Comment: Why do you need vector, Is ArrayList<> not enough ?

Comment: try fixing the code: `addEllement -> addElement`

Comment: you are thinking too much as c++, java has no structures, just use an ArrayList

Comment: use `Vector.addAll()`

Comment: `addElement` takes a `my_struct` while you try to add an array of `my_struct`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution ;)

> plugin_group_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(list_plugin_param));

Answer (score 0):

If its necessary for you to differentiate between the name, id and comment fields, try setting it to a map and then add it to a list.

Each line in the list should then represent the name, id and comment for a new row in the file.

Here is an outline of what you could possibly try:

```
    try 
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        //opening my file
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            HashMap<String,String> newLine = new HashMap<String,String>();
            String[] result = line.split("~");
             for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
             {
                 if(x==0)
                 {
                     newLine.put("name",result[x]);
                 }              
                 if(x==1)
                 {
                     newLine.put("id",result[x]);
                 }  
                 if(x==2)
                 {
                     newLine.put("comment",result[x]);
                 }
             }
             list.add(newLine);
        }
        fileReader.close();
    }
```